# Help improving my question

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

[GWT show weather](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10950773/gwt-show-weather) is being voted down, and I am not sure why.
Could you please have a look and suggest what is wrong with it, and how I can improve it?

Comment: I think that it is a shame that the question is closed especially since it has such a good answer.

Answer (score 4):

I guess it is being down-voted because you don't show what you have searched, or what you have tried. Not showing what you have tried leads users to think you just asked the question without even trying to achieve what you want, which means the question seems a lazy question, asked from who didn't even bother of trying before asking. The other reason is that the question is so generic that it is thought not to be useful for future readers. This is also the reason the question is being voted to be closed.

Both these reasons are reports in the tooltip for the down-vote button.

[image: screenshot]

Make the question more specific: Don't you know how to start, or don't you know how to do a specific thing?
Show your research, or what you tried. That would be helpful for the users to avoid suggesting something that.

In the case the question gets closed, you can still edit it to make more specific, or more detailed, and then flag it for moderation attention to be re-opened. If the moderators think the question can be re-opened, they will re-open it.

Answer (score 3):

Your question has received 3 [Not a real question](https://stackoverflow.com/faq#close) close votes, it is likely each of those close-voters also down voted your question.

NARQ votes are usually cast because the question is incomplete or overly broad, or unlikely to lead to a concise answer. You could possibly have staed *why* you thought serverside activity was strange. You also followed that statement with two very open ended questions along the generally frowned upon lines of *"what is better"* ([Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128548/what-stack-overflow-is-not/128562#128562)) and *"how can I do it"* (you have not included any explanation of what you have achieved so far).

You could edit your question even though you have already marked an answer. You probably won't regain the lost votes but at least you will have learnt how to ask a better quality question.

Comment: You may want to revisit that old "What SO is Not" FAQ sheet - the scope of that answer has changed, and I feel that this situation would be better explained by "Stack Overflow is not a research assistant".

Comment: Is there a way for me to see those NARQ votes?

Comment: Makoto, don't you think that if I tried to do something for myself and could not find the info; then it would be a legit question to ask how and if it can be done?

Comment: @kroiz Once you have enough rep you can see the `close` link and will be able to see the current close votes on a question.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your frustration but you must understand that things on Stack Overflow are somewhat.. different. It's not a help or support forum like many others and actually it's not like any other thing I know so I'll try to explain the uniqueness.

From the [about page](https://stackoverflow.com/about):

> Stack Overflow is a programming Q & A site

Not a forum - **Q & A site**.

Then in the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page:

> Have you thoroughly searched for an answer before asking your question? **Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you found and why it didn’t meet your needs**.

You missed that bold part - you said in your question that you researched the matter but failed to share any of this or to explain what you learned from that research.

Bottom line, Stack Overflow is trying its best to contain high quality questions, not just stuff like "it's not working please help", or "how to  do X or Y?" - of course such things exist but it doesn't mean they are good and should be there.

Hope this clarify some things and it's not too late - you can always edit your question adding more details and then it can be reopened and upvoted.

Comment: Sir, I don't agree, I wrote I did research to find out how to use weather in my application and I wrote what that research resulted in: "this is done server side" and I wrote why it did not meet my needs: load is on the server. Maybe my question was too concise and people that don't understand the subject are having hard time getting all this info from it but at least one person (LINEMAN78) did and gave me an excellent answer that I believe could help many other that will face this question.

Comment: @kroiz, I would not say that LINEMAN78 gave you an excellent answer. You were given enough information to solve your problem.

Comment: Sorry, I don't want to bicker but it is strange to me that all of you good people are having a different opinion about this issue than me. Yes the question was a very broad initially now that that was fixed what else do you think that can be done?

Comment: @kroiz I just said why your question is considered Not a Real Question on Stack Overflow. Just saying one sentence "this is done server side" is not considered explaining your whole research. Personally I am not familiar with any of the technical stuff and of course didn't vote.

Comment: @Ben, but I asked if x can be done. LINEMAN78 replied yes and explained how - that is what **Q & A site** is all about, so sorry I disagree with you too (but you are in good company here cause it seems that everybody disagree with me here too :) )

Comment: @kroiz and got two sentences and a couple of links as an answer. Like Shadow I know nothing about the subject and haven't voted but I wouldn't upvote this answer.

Comment: @kroiz well, your question might fit under "*your answer is provided along with the question, and you expect more answers*" which is listed under [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask) anyway I suggest to let it be. If you don't want to add more details to the question and got what you wanted no point to keep stirring the mud. :)